# Java Memory heap error using text and excel files

Tags: java

I'm writing a program that does the following tasks:

1. Cleans up Excel files (i.e. remove rows based on a condition).
2. Add data from notepad to a new Excel (say Result Excel).
3. Add the data from Cleaned Excel files to the Result Excel.

Below is my code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellStyle;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Font;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.IndexedColors;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class TextToExcelMultiple {
    static int counter = 1;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        File mainFolder = new File("C:\\D\\Mypath\\New");
        File[] files;
        int rowCount = 0;
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Result");
        CellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();// Create style
        Font font = workbook.createFont();// Create font
        font.setBoldweight(Font.BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD);// Make font bold
        style.setAlignment(CellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER);
        style.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.YELLOW.getIndex());
        style.setFillPattern(CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
        style.setFont(font);// set it to bold
        Row row;
        Cell cell;
        row = sheet.createRow(rowCount);
        cell = row.createCell(0);
        cell.setCellValue("NAME");
        cell = row.createCell(1);
        cell.setCellValue("TITLE");
        cell = row.createCell(2);
        cell.setCellValue("FIRM");
        cell = row.createCell(3);
        cell.setCellValue("ADDRESS 1");
        cell = row.createCell(4);
        cell.setCellValue("ADDRESS 2");
        cell = row.createCell(5);
        cell.setCellValue("ADDRESS 3");
        cell = row.createCell(6);
        cell.setCellValue("CITY");
        cell = row.createCell(7);
        cell.setCellValue("STATE");
        cell = row.createCell(8);
        cell.setCellValue("POSTAL CODE");
        cell = row.createCell(9);
        cell.setCellValue("COUNTRY");
        cell = row.createCell(10);
        cell.setCellValue("PHONE");
        cell = row.createCell(11);
        cell.setCellValue("FAX");
        cell = row.createCell(12);
        cell.setCellValue("URL");
        cell = row.createCell(13);
        cell.setCellValue("ISN");
        for (int i = 0; i < row.getLastCellNum(); i++) {
            row.getCell(i).setCellStyle(style);
        }
        rowCount = 1;
        if (mainFolder.isDirectory()) {
            files = mainFolder.listFiles();
            for (File file : files) {
                if (file.isDirectory()) {
                    files = file.listFiles();
                    for (File finalFile : files) {
                        String ext = FilenameUtils.getExtension(finalFile.getAbsolutePath());
                        if ((ext.contains("xls") && finalFile.getName().toLowerCase().contains("detail"))) {
                            cleanUpFile(finalFile);
                        }
                    }
                    for (File finalFile : files) {
                        String ext = FilenameUtils.getExtension(finalFile.getAbsolutePath());
                        if ((ext.equals("txt") && finalFile.getName().contains("brief"))
                                || (ext.contains("xls") && finalFile.getName().toLowerCase().contains("detail"))) {
                            int rowNumber = writeData(finalFile, sheet, rowCount, workbook);
                            rowCount = rowNumber;
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("C:\\D\\Mihir\\new.xls");
        workbook.write(outputStream);
        outputStream.close();
    }

    private static int writeData(File file, XSSFSheet sheet, int rowCount, XSSFWorkbook workbook) throws Exception {

        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fileInputStream));
        String x;
        Row row;
        Cell cell;
        String ext = FilenameUtils.getExtension(file.getAbsolutePath() + " \t " + file.getName());
        if (!ext.contains("xls")) {
            while ((x = br.readLine()) != null) {
                if (!(x.contains("NAME"))) {
                    row = sheet.createRow(rowCount);
                    String[] namesList = x.split(",(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)", -1);
                    int columnCount = 0;
                    for (String name : namesList) {
                        cell = row.createCell(columnCount);
                        cell.setCellValue(name.replace("\"", ""));
                        columnCount += 1;
                    }
                    rowCount += 1;
                }
            }
        }

        if (ext.contains("xls")) {
            int result = appendDataToExcel(file, workbook, rowCount, counter);
            counter = result;
        }

        br.close();
        fileInputStream.close();
        return rowCount;

    }

    private static void cleanUpFile(File file) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
        FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(new File(file.getAbsolutePath()));
        Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fin);
        Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
        Cell cell;
        for (int i = 0; i <= sheet.getLastRowNum(); i++) {
            cell = sheet.getRow(i).getCell(1);
            if (cell == null) {
                sheet.removeRow(sheet.getRow(i));
                int rowIndex = i;
                int lastRowNum = sheet.getLastRowNum();

                if (rowIndex >= 0 && rowIndex <= lastRowNum) {
                    sheet.shiftRows(rowIndex + 1, lastRowNum, -1);
                }
            }
        }
        fin.close();
        FileOutputStream outFile = new FileOutputStream(new File(file.getAbsolutePath()));
        wb.write(outFile);
        wb.close();
        outFile.close();
    }

    private static int appendDataToExcel(File file, XSSFWorkbook workbook, int rowCount, int counter) throws Exception {

        String path = file.getAbsolutePath();
        FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(new File(path));
        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fin);
        XSSFSheet sheet1 = wb.getSheetAt(0);
        int noOfRows = sheet1.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        Cell cell;
        XSSFRow row;
        for (int i = 1; i < noOfRows; i++) {
            row = sheet.getRow(counter);
            cell = row.getCell(13);
            if (cell == null || cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK) {
                cell = row.createCell(13);
            }
            Cell cell1 = sheet1.getRow(i).getCell(1);
            if (cell1 != null && !cell1.equals("")) {
                cell.setCellValue(sheet1.getRow(i).getCell(1).toString() + "\t" + counter);
            }
            counter++;
        }
        wb.close();
        fin.close();
        counter = rowCount;
        return (counter);
    }

}
```

Previously I used to call `cleanUpFile(file)` method, And this use to give me the below exception.

Later on I tried to first clean files and then run the program on the cleaned files But still I get the same exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.grow(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.ensureCapacity(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.internal.MemoryPackagePartOutputStream.write(MemoryPackagePartOutputStream.java:88)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Cursor._save(Cursor.java:590)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Cursor.save(Cursor.java:2544)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.XmlObjectBase.save(XmlObjectBase.java:223)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet.write(XSSFSheet.java:2972)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet.commit(XSSFSheet.java:2927)
    at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocumentPart.onSave(POIXMLDocumentPart.java:323)
    at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocumentPart.onSave(POIXMLDocumentPart.java:327)
    at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocument.write(POIXMLDocument.java:195)
    at TextToExcelMultiple.main(TextToExcelMultiple.java:100)
```

And when I click on `at TextToExcelMultiple.main(TextToExcelMultiple.java:100)` it points out to `workbook.write(outputStream);`

I've got really big set of files.

One more thing: **when I comment out the below block and run it**, it works fine:

```
for (File finalFile : files) {
        String ext = FilenameUtils.getExtension(finalFile.getAbsolutePath());
            if ((ext.equals("txt") && finalFile.getName().contains("brief"))
            || (ext.contains("xls") && finalFile.getName().toLowerCase().contains("detail"))) {
                int rowNumber = writeData(finalFile, sheet, rowCount, workbook);
                    rowCount = rowNumber;
                }
     }
```

Going through some other SO posts, I've added the below in my arguments:

```
-Xms1100m -Xmx1100m
```

When I try to increase heap memory `-Xms1150m -Xmx2048m` it gives me below error:

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for 2097152KB object heap
```

Since my free memory available is around 1150MB:

[image]

Also if I deploy this as a swing app in my client's system, what all should be taken care before doing so?

How can I run this full program without facing the exception?

Comment: Looks like the problem is located inside of Apache POI. What if you prepare all your data outside of excel file, let say in a text file and when all your data is prepared, you load it to your excel file ?

Comment: Do you mean that I convert the `excel` into a text and use it? or save the Excel result to a text and use it?

Comment: It may and will affect the performance, so if it is not critical, generate all information outside of excel file. For example: create new text (csv) file and populate it with data you want to be in the result excel file. When your text (csv) file is generated, create new excel file and transfer text (csv) data to this new excel file.

Comment: @RafaelOsipov, the problem come up here, In my current process, First I read the text from text files and add it to Result Excel, next I read the data from Excel and place beside the current rows in my result excel. Can I do the same with csv?

Comment: csv is a simple text file. If it is more convenient use another text format. Make several text files, like `1.txt`, `2.txt`, `3.txt`, populate these files according to your task, then create new empty excel file, and read contents of these txt files to your excel file. Apache POI fails when you invoke some heavy action over excel file. Now, use Apache POI only to populate empty excel file from txt file(s).

Comment: Upon implementing suggested approach use profiler to control memory consumption in your code.